# What kind of grammar is this: "Set-Cookie:" Name "=" Value *(";" Attribute)

Tags: rfc, notation

It doesn't look like any of the [BNF family](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form).
I have seen this in several RFC papers, for example [HTML 1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2109), but it is never explained.
I can't find anything other than formatting guidelines on the [RFC site](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc-style-guide/rfc-style) either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an "augmented BNF" as explained in http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec2.html.